# apostrophe in PHP string

Tags: php

This is weird! I have a form which gets info from a DB and then fills in a form with the details. I am trying to cater for cases where a person has a name like O'Neill. At the top of the page (outside the actual form itself) is a line that echoes the user's name to the screen:

```
<h2>Member Details for <?php echo $thefn; ?></h2>
```

And this does indeed display on the page properly, i.e., **Member Details for Mike O'Neill**
However, in the actual form, where the code runs:

```
<td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='fname' value='$thefn' size='30' maxlength='30'>"; ?></td>
```

The name is shown with everything after the apostrophe gone! The variable is the same, so what am I doing wrong? This has got me tearing my hair out (and there's a fair amount of that!)

Comment: Escape the single quote or wrap your attribute values in double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I put in my name as:

```
' /><script type="text/javascript">alert("You've just been hacked!");</script><input type="hidden" name="lol" value='hax
```

Now what?

```
htmlspecialchars($thefn)
```

Should help.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes `" "` in your HTML like so :

```
echo "<input type='text' name='fname' value=\"$thefn\" size='30' maxlength='30'>";
```

Note that you have to escape them with `\` since you already use double quotes to delimit your string (in PHP). Another solution is to use single-quotes on the PHP side (`echo ' ';`) and use double quotes inside the string, so that you don't need escaping.

Also note that this code is vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), you can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent that, here's the corrected code (both the XSS and the quotes) :

```
echo '<input type="text" name="fname" value="'.htmlspecialchars($thefn).'" size="30" maxlength="30">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the obvious security red herring here (I assume the format of your `$thefn` variable is correct for going between single quotes in HTML), I would be wrapping the PHP variables inside of {} brackets, like so. This has two major advantages. One - it is easier to spot replaceable parts, plus, makes it crystal clear to PHP what part is dynamic. Two - you can use fancier variables, like arrays. `{$my_array['my_key']}`.

```
<td>
<?php
    echo "<input type='text' name='fname' value='{$thefn}' size='30' maxlength='30'>";
?>
</td>
```

See also: [PHP string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) (in the manual)